# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library not working

Tags: php, macos, command-line-interface, homebrew, php-7.1

I cannot for the life of me figure out what triggered this, and no other post seems to cover it. Can of youshed some light and help me resolve this matter? I am suing homebrew for my php. How can I go back to business as usual via php71 or greater? I am using a mac.

***THE FOLLOWING IS THE ERROR:***

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.1
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-intl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

Comment: Well the error is pretty self explanatory actually. You're missing some extension files (/usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so and /usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so) which are enabled in your php.ini . Also it seems you're trying to reload mcrypt (which I assume is due to an extra `extension=mcrypt.so` at the end of your php.ini

Comment: @Cemal right so how do I resolve this? You left that part out!

Comment: open up `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini` find `extension=intl.so` and add `#` at the beginning of the line. and delete files `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-intl.ini`and `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini` and restart your web server.

Comment: Are you using `intl` extension? If so, reinstalling it will also solve your problems (to a point, you still we'll have to remove those 2 .ini files)

Comment: @Cemal dint want to leave you hanging, it turn out my pear installation screwed me big time, and I uninstalled it, along with pcel, php71 and nginx, then reinstalled nginx with php72... The rest is history, but thanks for trying to rescue me good friend!

Answer (score 0):

So the short answer to this is, I ripped out Pear and pcel and anything else related to it I had just added, along with php71/Nginx and reinstalled php72/nginx (more os to be up to date as well), but once I symlinked it all restored to working form.

The real culprit here was pear, as I was originally trying to install xdebug, but pear/pcel took over my php setup and shit hit the fan!

We are no in a much better place, backtrace your steps like I did folks!